# Crontab not running feh correctly on two screens in i3 (display variable set to :0)

Tags: cron, i3, wallpaper, feh

I have two screens and I have a script to set a new wallpaper in i3 every day. The script basically downloads an image and then runs following command

```
convert {save_location} -trim JPG:- | feh --bg-max -
```

This works perfectly when ran interactively - each screen gets a copy of the same wallpaper like this

```
|@@@@@@@@|  |@@@@@@@@|
|@@hello@|  |@@hello@|
|@@@@@@@@|  |@@@@@@@@|
```

The display variable is set to :0

```
echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

However if I run it with `crontab -e`:

```
0 1 * * * DISPLAY=:0 python .../change_wallpaper.py
```

then it does not set a copy of wallpaper on each screen. It treats both screens as one and sets this wallpaper into the center of a "combined screen":

```
|----@@@@|  |@@@@----|
|----@@he|  |llo@----|
|----@@@@|  |@@@@----|
```

This obviously looks ugly.

I searched but could not find a good advice how to solve this. Maybe someone from the community would have some tips. Thanks a lot in advance

My environment:
Ubuntu 20.04, i3, gdm

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after reading the source code of [feh](https://github.com/derf/feh), I decided that the problem is related to xinerama. Although not being able to solve this in a beautiful way, here is a script that serves as a workaround:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Compute screen size
size=$(xrandr | grep *+ -m 1 \
        | sed -r 's/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+x[0-9]+).*$/\1/')
# then manually collate a combined picture for two screens and
# launch feh without xinerama functionality  
convert [path/to/picture] \
  -trim \
  -resize $size \
  -background black -compose Copy \
  -gravity center -extent $size \
  -quality 92 +duplicate +append JPG:- \
  | feh --bg-max --no-xinerama -
```

As written in the script comments, the script computes the screen size and then manually collates a combined picture for two screens (with the imagemagick tool) and launches feh without xinerama functionality at all.

This works in cron as well as interactively. However, this would probably not work very well if the screens are of different sizes.